# Activities&Places and History in GWT

Tags: gwt

Activities&Places and History mechanism in GWT is used to Navigate The pages.
Then what is the basic difference between the two ?
If we can Use History Mechanism for navigation then why should we go for Activities and Places and vice versa ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question to post the [minimal code that reproduces the problem that you're asking about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That will give us a better chance of being able to help without asking for clarification

Comment: Basically, Activities and Places framework is built on History mechanism and can be used with MVP architecture. An activity simply represents something the user is doing. A place is a Java object representing a particular state of the UI. Detailed explanation is in the [documentation](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html).